# Binding Shopping Cart Check box Session onto another Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am new to asp.net and I am trying to make a shopping cart. I have a shop set up that has a list of school supplies and a check box next to each one with a "Add to Cart" button on the bottom. I want to store only the checked items into a session and call it to another gridview on my Shopping Cart page. For some reason my gridview on my Shopping cart page is not appearing.

Shop.aspx

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" DataFormatString="{0:c2}" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add To Cart">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbAdd" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table] ORDER BY [Id], [Name], [Price]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

</div>
<br />
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
```

Shop.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)//bind list to gridview
    {


    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();//create new datatable
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("ID"), new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("Country") });
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvProducts.Rows)//for each row in the gridview
        {
            CheckBox ckRow = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ckAdd");

            if (ckRow !=null && ckRow.Checked)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add("ID");
                dt.Columns.Add("Name");
                dt.Columns.Add("Price");

                Session["ShoppingCart"] = dt;//store datatable as session called ShoppingCart
            }

            Response.Redirect("~/ShoppingCart.aspx");
        }
```

ShoppingCart.aspx

```
    <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
<asp:GridView ID="gvProductsList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Textbox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Count")%>'></asp:Textbox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Total">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblProductTotal" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Quantity"))*Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Price"))%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text="Order Total: "></asp:Label>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

ShoppingCart.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["ShoppingCart"];

            gvProductsList.DataSource = dt;
            gvProductsList.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
    List<GridViewRow> gridcheckedrows = gvProducts.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().
                                        Where(x => (x.FindControl("cbAdd") as CheckBox)
                                       .Checked == true).ToList();
```

I used below custom data to bind the grid `gvProducts`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Id");
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Price");
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "1";
            dr[1] = "Sharique";
            dr[2] = "120";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "2";
            dr[1] = "Ansari";
            dr[2] = "100";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            gvProducts.DataSource = dt;
            gvProducts.DataBind();
        }


    }
```

use this to bind you grid `gvProductsList`

```
List<GridViewRow> gridcheckedrows = gvProducts.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Where(x => (x.FindControl("cbAdd") as CheckBox).Checked == true).ToList();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Price");
        dt.Columns.Add("Count");
        dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gridcheckedrows)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Id"] = gvr.Cells[0].Text;
            dr["Name"] = gvr.Cells[1].Text;
            dr["Price"] = gvr.Cells[2].Text;
            dr["Count"] = "1";
            dr["Quantity"] = "2";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        }
        gvProductsList.DataSource = dt;
        gvProductsList.DataBind();
```

and for grid `gvProductsList` use below html

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProductsList" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Count")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Total">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProductTotal" runat="server" Text='<%# ((Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Quantity")))*(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Price"))))%>'></asp:Label>

                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text="Order Total: "></asp:Label>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That would go in the foreach loop right? After doing that I got a InvalidCastException in my ShoppingCart.aspx.cs for "DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["ShoppingCart"];".

Comment: @Jamie to set use this `Session["cart"] = gridcheckedrows;` and to again get use this `List<GridViewRow> gcheckedrows = (List<GridViewRow>)Session["cart"];` you bind your grid using datasourse as `gcheckedrows `

Comment: @Jamie no need of foreach loop just write only one line which i wrote.

Comment: My gridview still isn't showing up on my ShoppingCart page. Do you know why?

Comment: I got the Gridview to show however the data is still not filled in. I just end up with a ID column that's blank.

Comment: @Jamie You can accept this as answers if this helps you, it will help other user who will visit this page